# How to install notepadqq in Solus Linux?

Tags: solus

someone knows how to install notepadqq in the Linux Solus distribution ?.
Or do you recommend something similar to notepadqq, please.
Thank you

Comment: I will answer, finally I could install, via snap. In case someone needs it. In Linux Solus terminal.  "sudo snap install notepadqq"

Answer (score 0):

It is now already on the Solus repository, you could install it by running `sudo eopkg it notepadqq` on the terminal, or installing it from the Software Center manually.